# Two dead beans on a stone

Tags: no-computers, cipher, history

Samuel Bean, a Canadian doctor, had a tombstone erected in Rushes Cemetery near Crosshill, Wellesley Township, Ontario, for his first two wives, Henrietta and Susanna. The original stone was carved in the 1860s and became badly weathered; the following picture shows the more durable replica made to replace it in the 1980s.

[image: stone]

**What is the message encrypted on the stone, and how can it be decrypted?**

Note: the solution is already known, so you could find it by Googling. But it'll be more fun if you manage it by yourself, so [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) and no cheating! :-)

Comment: It says "aged 23" in the middle in plain text

Comment: @Richard True. What about the rest of the text? :-)

Comment: I also see "lies" and "RIP"

Comment: The 2 bottom lines have an interesting pattern.

Comment: Is Susanna died in storm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The message is written in this jagged spiral:[image: 1]]

> In memoriam: Henrietta, 1st wife of S. Bean, M.D., who died 27th Sep. 1865 aged 23 years 2 months & 17 days, & Susanna, his 2nd wife, who died 27th April 1867 aged 26 years 10 months & 15 days. 2 better wives 1 man never had. They were gifts from God but are now in heaven. May God help me, S. B., to meet them there.